# How do I find a 4 digit unicode character using this perl one liner?

Tags: perl, unicode

I have a file with this unicode character `ỗ`

[image]

File saved in notepad as UTF-8

I tried this line

`C:\blah>perl -wln -e "/\x{1ed7}/ and print;" blah.txt`

But it's not picking it up.  If the file has a letter like 'a'(unicode hex 61), then `\x{61}` picks it up. But for a 4 digit unicode character, I have an issue picking up the character.

Comment: Have you instructed perl that you have input file in UTF8 format?

Comment: You can show the character code that  perl actually read by running `perl -n -E "say printf '%vX', $_" blah.txt`. Check if the output matches `\x{1ed7}`. You would also probably have to check what code page CMD is using for output, and also add an UTF-8 IO-layer on the input file handle (e.g. `perl -Ci ...`) and the correct output IO layer

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks. If I do `xxd -p blah.txt` to show the hex in there, then I get `efbbbfe1bb97`.  The efbbbf is a utf-8 bom. And e1bb97 is the utf-8 encoding of the character.   Any idea why if I do `perl -n -E "say printf '%vX', $_" blah.txt`   it outputs `EF.BB.BF.E1.BB.971`  i.e. it outputs a 1 on the end?  Similarly if I have an ascii file with just the letter 'z' in it  (7a in hex), and I do xxd -p a.txt, it shows 7a. But that perl line says 7A1 (i.e. it puts a 1 on the end)

Comment: @barlop How are you able to run `xxd` ? In CMD prompt I get `'xxd' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: @barlop In CMD and `blah.txt` saved in `notepad.exe` with a single character `ỗ` and running `perl -nE "say sprintf '%vX', $_" blah.txt` I get output `E1.BB.97`. So I do not get the last `1` as you did. Maybe you are printing something after the character that outputs as a `1` ?

Comment: @HåkonHægland  A) it comes with cygwin  `C:\cygwin64\bin\xxd.exe`  or `C:\cygwin\bin\xxd.exe`  B)  (less well known!) It  comes with VIM since VIM 7! `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\xxd.exe`   https://superuser.com/questions/497953/convert-hex-dump-of-file-to-binary-program-file-on-windows/638850#638850       here https://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/vim/pc/gvim82.zip    in  `.\vim\vim82\xxd.exe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had the right idea with using `/\x{1ed7}/`.  The problem is that your regex wants to match characters but you're giving it bytes.  You'll need to tell Perl to decode the bytes from UTF-8 when it reads them and then encode them to UTF-8 when it writes them:

```
perl -CiO -ne "/\x{1ed7}/ and print" blah.txt
```

The -C option controls how Unicode semantics are applied to input and output filehandles.  So for example `-CO` (capital 'o' for 'output') is equivalent to adding this before the start of your script:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8")
```

Similarly, `-CI` is equivalent to:

```
binmode(STDIN, ":utf8")
```

But in your case, you're not using STDIN.  Instead, the `-n` is wrapping a loop around your code that opens each file listed on the command-line.  So you can instead use `-Ci` to add the `':utf8'` I/O layer to each file Perl opens for input.  You can combine the `-Ci` and the `-CO` as: `-CiO`

Comment: Thanks. So when reading telling it that you are reading it as UTF-8, then the thing you specify with \x is a utf-32 or utf-16 code.. But when not telling it you are reading UTF-8 then you specify bytes that are essentially utf-8 ?!

Comment: If putting aside output so just looking at how it reads it, then when I do `perl -n -Ci -E "say printf '%vX', $_" blah.txt` i.e. with that say .... line to show what it's reading..    re my utf-8 file.  Lowercase i shows `FEFF.1ED71`  (a utf-16 thing 'cos that's a UTF-16 BOM at the start there).  And uppercase I  shows utf-8.  So either way it seems to be able to read it without confusion. And somehow even just the input can involve conversion e.g. with lowercase i.

Comment: @barlop Windows programs like to add a BOM to utf-8 encoded files.

Comment: @barlop *the thing you specify with \x is a utf-32 or utf-16 code*... No. It's a Unicode codepoint. Internally Perl uses utf-8, but that's transparent to the user. You just have to tell Perl what encoding the source data is using when it's converted to the internal format.

Comment: @Shawn ok thanks I see code point is independent of encoding.  like a 3 part system. code point, encoding and glyph.

Comment: Correct, and to make things even more complicated, a single glyph can be composed from multiple codepoints. For example, `"\x{6f}\x{302}\x{303}"` should render the same glyph as `"\x{1ed7}"` (but it seems to be somewhat system dependent).

Comment: @GrantMcLean so is the "\x{..}\x{..}" specifying bytes or specifying code points?

Comment: Why is `-Ci` so `perl -Ci -n -E "say printf '%vX', $_"  blah.txt`  outputting `FEFF.1ED71`  i.e. outputting UTF-16 ?   (The 1 at the end is a weird thing on my system apparently others using perl don't have that, so that aside).  That FEFF is a UTF-16 BE BOM.   `perl -Ci -n -E "say printf '%vX', $_"  blah.txt | xxd -r -p >a.a`   then `file a.a` shows "a.a: Big-endian UTF-16 Unicode text"   Without -Ci  so `perl -n -E "say printf '%vX', $_"  blah.txt` then it shows `EF.BB.BF.E1.BB.971`

Comment: `FEFF` is just the codepoint number of the BOM character, it's not specifically UTF16 and in fact in this case it has been decoded from UTF8 into Perl's internal encoding. UTF8 doesn't need a BOM, but Windows apps like to add one to indicate that the data is not in Windows proprietary 'ANSI' encoding. The extra '1' on the end is the return code of the `printf` function. Normally you'd use either `say sprintf ...` (note the leading 's') or `printf ...` rather than using both `say` and `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

Your script works fine. The problem is the unicode you're using for searching. Since your file is utf-8 then your unique search parameters need to be E1, BB, or 97. Check the below file encoding and how that changes the search criteria.

```
 UTF-8 Encoding:    0xE1 0xBB 0x97
 UTF-16 Encoding:   0x1ED7
 UTF-32 Encoding:   0x00001ED7
```

Resource https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1ED7

Comment: thanks, yeah this works `perl -wln -e "/\x{e1}\x{bb}\x{97}/ and print;" blah.txt`

Comment: @barlop, Usually, it's better to decode inputs, encode outputs: `perl -CSD -wlne"print if /\x{1ED7}/" blah.txt`

Comment: You may also have to change codepage to 65001 for the output to be correct. My CMD used code page 437 so the output looked like this `ß╗ù`

Comment: @HåkonHægland yeah chcp 65001 and a font that supports the character, like courier new.  I was putting aside the cmd idiosyncracies!